# Sort Using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need to sort the below xml by
/parentList/employeesList/personalInfo/middleName

using XSLT. I'm unable to generate the format I'm expecting.The one with Middle name "John" should come up in the output xml. Can you someone help me on this. Below are my XML and XSL's

**XML :**

```
<parentList>

    <employeesList>
        <personalInfo>
            <middleName>Mike</middleName>
            <lastName>S</lastName>
        </personalInfo>
        <mailingAddress>
            <postalCode>12345</postalCode>
            <cityName>CoEmployee CityName</cityName>
            <state>PA</state>
            <addressLineText>CoEmployee Full Address</addressLineText>
        </mailingAddress>
    </employeesList>
    <employeesList>
        <personalInfo>
            <middleName>John</middleName>
            <lastName>G</lastName>
        </personalInfo>
        <mailingAddress>
            <postalCode>12345</postalCode>
            <cityName>CoEmployee CityName</cityName>
            <state>PA</state>
            <addressLineText>CoEmployee Full Address</addressLineText>
        </mailingAddress>
    </employeesList>
</parentList>
```

**XSL:**

```
 <xsl:template match="parentList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>

            <xsl:sort select="/employeesList/personalInfo/middleName" order="ascending"/> 
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the sort inside a for-each:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parentList">
        <xsl:for-each select="employeesList">
            <xsl:sort select="personalInfo/middleName" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the XPath expression that you are using in your `select` attribute. It's an absolute expression (starts with `/`) but there your root element is not `employeesList`.

When you match `parentList`, you apply templates to its children, which provide the context for the `sort` element. That means that a relative XPath expression in the `select` attribute of `sort` should be in the context of `employeesList`.

It should work if you simply change your template to this:

```
<xsl:template match="parentList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="personalInfo/middleName" order="ascending"/> 
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```